# views pagination pager add | to the li

Tags: 7, paging

How do I add "|" to views pager when you are displaying numbers. See the example
below

previous   1 | 2 | 3   next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options:
1. Using the view's tempate file
2. The easiest and my favorite in that case - using css :after selector to add the '|' to the li's

Hope that helps.

Comment: In would use css :after too. But in this situation it will not work. I will look at the tpl thanks

Comment: Use the 'information' link on the view's display, it gives you all the template suggestions you'll need :)

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to include info on *how* to do it using the view's template file?